# Email Field Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I am using an email validation script for my form. I am trying to add a function that returns TRUE if the email field contains certain spammy domains, like "mail.ru" and others... Here's what I have, that's not working. Any help would be appreciated!

Also, any way to expand this to add multiple values to search the email input?

"Email" is the field name in my form.

Thanks, Nick

```
function DoCustomValidation() {
    var frm = document.forms["contactus"];
    if (frm.Email.value.includes("mail.ru")) {
        sfm_show_error_msg('Sorry, no spam allowed!');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give details about what is not working? what error is coming up? At which point does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this

```
function DoCustomValidation() {
  var frm = document.forms["contactus"];
  var spams = ['mail.ru', 'something.ru']; //Keep spam sites in this array
  var i, token = frm.Email.value, hasSpam = false;

  for (i = 0; i < spams.length; i++) {
    if (token.includes(spams[i])) {
      hasSpam = true; 
      break;
    }
  }

  if (hasSpam) {
    sfm_show_error_msg('Sorry, no spam allowed!');
  }

  return hasSpam;
}
```

Comment: `return includeSpam` that variable is undefined.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! The above solution worked.